# Benchmark api return serialize array but cannot convert to unserialize in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, serialization, benchmarking

I have a serialized array that come from benchmark api.I want it to normal php array and i used unserialize but it is not working and return blank.Anyone can advise? Thank you so much for your help.

This string is i got from benchmark api in codeigniter PHP

```
a:1:{
  i:0;a:7:{
          s:8:"sequence";s:1:"1";
          s:5:"email";s:21:"johnny188@gmail.com";
          s:4:"name";s:8:"Johnny";
          s:7:"logdate";s:21:"May 22 2020, 04:57 PM";
          s:8:"linkname";N;
          s:6:"reason";N;
          s:6:"counts";s:2:"66";s:6:"device";s:15:"Desktop, Win 10";}}
```

Comment: There are multiple errors in that serialized string. It looks like It's been modified after it was created. 1. There are 8 array items, so `a:7` should be `a:8` 2. For your email, `s:21` should be `s:19` since the email has 19 characters, not 21. 3. For your name, `s:8` should be `s:6` since the name only has 6 characters.

Comment: Another issue, all the line breaks/tabs/spaces. The string needs to be in one line. [Here's a demo](https://3v4l.org/RlWsR) after the serialized string have been fixed with the issues I've pointed out.